# Text mining - Mining tweet with multiple terms at the same time using Stream in Python

Tags: python, twitter, text-mining, sentiment-analysis

I am working on text mining in Python using twitter data to study sentiments on IPO(Initial Public Offering) for Indian Companies. I need help to extract tweets that have multiple terms in them - all inclusive. For example I want tweets in which all three words "Mahindra", "Logistics" and "IPO" is there. Is there a way to do this using the stream function in Python?

I have attached my code also

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':

#This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
l = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


stream = Stream(auth, l)
#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'Mahindra' 'Logistics' 'IPO'
stream.filter(track=['Mahindra,Logistics,IPO'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to comment on your question so I had to post an answer.

I haven't looked into Twitter APIs I do have an alternative though. You can use [Twitter Scraper](https://github.com/taspinar/twitterscraper) and  achieve the same without having to do a lot of coding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be only a (incomplete) python fragment, but it still looks familiar to me.
I use the following script to fetch data from the Twitter Stream API:

```
# To run this code, first edit config.py with your configuration (Auth data), then install necessary modules, then:
#
# Call
#
# mkdir data
# python twitter_stream_download.py -q apple -d data
#
#
# It will produce the list of tweets for the query "apple"
# in the file data/stream_apple.json

# analyse tweets with jq:
# cat stream_apple.json | jq -s '.[] |  {user: .user.name}

import tweepy
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import argparse
import string
import config
import json

def get_parser():
    """Get parser for command line arguments."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Twitter Downloader")
    parser.add_argument("-q",
                        "--query",
                        dest="query",
                        help="Query/Filter",
                        default='-')
    parser.add_argument("-l",
                        "--lang",
                        dest="languages",
                        help="Languages",
                        default='en')

    parser.add_argument("-d",
                        "--data-dir",
                        dest="data_dir",
                        help="Output/Data Directory")
    return parser


class MyListener(StreamListener):
    """Custom StreamListener for streaming data."""

    def __init__(self, data_dir=".", query=""):
        query_fname = format_filename(query)
        self.outfile = "%s/stream_%s.json" % (data_dir, query_fname)
        print("Writing to '{}'").format(self.outfile)


    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                print(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
            time.sleep(5)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            print("rate limited - to many connection attempts. Please wait.")
            return False
        else:
            print(status)
        return True


def format_filename(fname):
    """Convert file name into a safe string.

    Arguments:
        fname -- the file name to convert
    Return:
        String -- converted file name
    """
    return ''.join(convert_valid(one_char) for one_char in fname)


def convert_valid(one_char):
    """Convert a character into '_' if invalid.

    Arguments:
        one_char -- the char to convert
    Return:
        Character -- converted char
    """
    valid_chars = "-_.%s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
    if one_char in valid_chars:
        return one_char
    else:
        return '_'

@classmethod
def parse(cls, api, raw):
    status = cls.first_parse(api, raw)
    setattr(status, 'json', json.dumps(raw))
    return status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    auth = OAuthHandler(config.consumer_key, config.consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(config.access_token, config.access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener(args.data_dir, args.query))
    twitter_stream.filter(track=[args.query], languages=[args.languages], async=False)
```

Create an output dir first, and a file config.py

```
consumer_key = "7r..."
consumer_secret = "gp..."
access_token = "5Q..."
access_secret = "a3..."
```

Then call it like this:

```
python twitter_stream_download.py --query #Logistics" -d data
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue (and I needed to look for tweets that were more than a week old). And since existing packages were too slow I decided to create a small package called [Twper](https://github.com/jungerm2/Twper). I think you might find it interesting. There's an example in the Readme that solves ur exact issue.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this package and it is relatively new but hopefully it'll help.